# How to write this styling in latest implementation of CSS3's Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I figured out how to achieve a style with the 2009 implementation of flexbox, but there are two other implementations. The short-lived 2011 and part of 2012 syntax and then the current and final syntax.

How can I write this code in the current and final implementation?

If you can also do the 2011 implementation, that would be great!

I'm looking for with vendor-prefixes.

```css
display:-moz-box;
display:-webkit-box;
display:box;
-moz-box-align:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
box-align:center;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
box-pack:center;
```

Comment: If you're looking for a chart of all of the property name/values from each draft, you can find it here:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6.  A new set of Flexbox mixins is arriving in the next Compass (for Sass) version that does all the work for you.

Comment: @cimmanon thank you. The link should help. I don't use Sass, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete set of properties would look like this:

```
.foo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;

  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Note that `row`/`horizontal` is the default direction, and it isn't necessary to add it unless you're overriding it from a previous `column`/`vertical` declaration elsewhere.

Setting the flex container to inline follows the same naming conventions as the other inline properties (eg. inline-block, inline-table, etc.):

```
.foo {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

If you're doing this specifically for vertical centering, Firefox under the 2009 implementation can sometimes be a problem because it doesn't always wrap properly.  My recommendation is to use different properties for the 2009 properties compared to the modern properties like this:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mxuFa

```
li {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  /* vertical centering for legacy, horizontal centering for modern */
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* modern Flexbox only */
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* legacy Flexbox only */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
}
```

Comment: I know i'm not use inline-flex. But, can you add to your answer a second set of styles that would achieve the same effect with the complete set of properties for inline-flex? In the case that I use inline-flex and I can refer to this in the future. The effect I am trying to achieve is horizontal and vertical centering.

Comment: I tried it out and the paragraph inside #topBar is still top-aligned and not horizontally and vertically centred. Oddly enough, when I try just the 2009 version, as in my question, it is centred. Here is the page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/setup/setup.html Any idea why the p in #topBar is not being centred?

Comment: Yes, there's subtle differences in the behavior of the 2009 draft compared to the modern drafts.  What you're overlooking is the `align-items` property, which defaults to `stretch` (as in stretch to fill the available space along the cross axis, or vertically in our case) and doesn't exist in the 2009 draft.  The code towards the end of my answer is the most efficient way to write for vertical alignment of a single or anonymous flex item for all drafts.  Demo for your code:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/knJcB

Comment: Also, the `rgb(R, G, B)` color format doesn't need a hex fallback, it's been around forever.  Only `rgba(R, G, B, A)` needs a fallback.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Could you do one more thing for me, add to your answer how one would horizontally and vertically centre an inline-flex item? If you could, make it separate from the flex-box version above, but in the same answer?

Comment: The code+demo from my answer is for an inline flex container with an anonymous flex item (but it works the same way if it has an image or some other element inside it):  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/knJcB

Comment: does it work for block level flex-items too, like a div with display:flex ?

Comment: Yes.  All Flexbox properties work the same way for inline flex containers as they do for normal flex containers.